# VBA Script round function not displaying result as in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script running that rounds invoice figures down to 2 decimal places however I want my script to round up the number if the third decimal is a 5, The problem I have is that if I do this as a formula in excel it works but in my script it doesn't .

Starting number 152.575

in Excel **as a formula**  =Round(A1,2) / result is 152.58

in VBA the result is 152.57

```
Dim n
n = Cells(1, "A")
n = round(n, 2)
```

What am I missing in my code ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: `n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(n, 2)`

Comment: `0.5` or anything ending with `5` gets a special treatment as `Round` in VBA is using "bankers rounding". Just to quote the source: "two nearest integers are rounded to the nearest even integer", meaning that your `.575` is being rounded down to `.570`, while `.576` would be rounded up to `.580`. In order to achieve clearer (more "mathematical") results, use `WorksheetFunction.Round` instead. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: If you search google for `difference between round and Application.WorksheetFunction.Round`, you will get the explanation in case you are interested...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, much appreciated

Comment: Suggest also looking at the Wikipedia article on [Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) for discussion of all types of algorithms.

Comment: Why didn't at least one of you make an answer? All the information is here.